# Multiple orderby within Criteria

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I currently use the Criteria to filter a collection of objects. But when I want to achieve with 2 orderBy fields, only the first is considered. I do not understand.

```
$events = new Collections\ArrayCollection($results);
$dateFrom = new \DateTime($date);
$dateTo   = new \DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($date . ' + 1 day')));

$criteria = Criteria::create()
    ->where(Criteria::expr()->eq('activity', $activity));

$criteria->orderBy(array(
    "time" => "ASC",
    "title" => "ASC"
));
```

How can I make it work with two orderby fields and not only the first ?

Thank you in advance for any answers !

Comment: The answer you posted where you provided additional information has been deleted instead of merged into your question, which is what they should have done. Nonetheless, I've updated my answer accordingly. Make sure you check it out!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, assuming that `$criteria` is then applied correctly to the `ArrayCollection`.

Judging by the names of your fields you're trying to order by, it's possible that `title` doesn't affect the order because `time` doesn't repeat among the elements in the collection.

If this isn't the case, please provide more information on the results you're getting and I will update my answer.

**Update (in response to additional data provided that has since been deleted):**

You *are* sorting the collection correctly. The problem is that you're then feeding the `ArrayCollection` into the `Paginator`, which apparently cannot sort by more than one field.

There's an open issue in Knp's tracker about this: https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle/issues/109.